# Storing Docker DB data to local persistence directory

Tags: oracle, docker

I have an app that uses Oracle as its DB and I'm tyring to get a Dockerized version of Oracle working locally. I'm using [this Oracle image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-12c/) which so far is working beautifully and completely as advertised! I pulled it and am running it like so:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 sath89/oracle-12c
```

It takes a while for the container to fire up and run, several minutes actually. Below you can see me running the `docker logs` command several times over the course of about ~3 mins and getting more and more output each time until it is finally stood up and running!

```
MyUser:~ myuser$ docker logs f0a177ed739f
Database not initialized. Initializing database.
Starting tnslsnr

MyUser:~ myuser$ docker logs f0a177ed739f
Database not initialized. Initializing database.
Starting tnslsnr
Copying database files
1% complete
3% complete
11% complete

MyUser:~ myuser$ docker logs f0a177ed739f
Database not initialized. Initializing database.
Starting tnslsnr
Copying database files
1% complete
3% complete
11% complete
18% complete
26% complete
37% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
40% complete
45% complete

MyUser:~ myuser$ docker logs f0a177ed739f
Database not initialized. Initializing database.
Starting tnslsnr
Copying database files
1% complete
3% complete
11% complete
18% complete
26% complete
37% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
40% complete
45% complete
50% complete
55% complete
56% complete
60% complete
62% complete
Completing Database Creation
66% complete
70% complete
73% complete
85% complete
96% complete
100% complete
Look at the log file "/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/xe/xe.log" for further details.
Configuring Apex console
Database initialized. Please visit http://#containeer:8080/em http://#containeer:8080/apex for extra configuration if needed
Starting web management console

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Starting import from '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d':
found file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d//docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
[IMPORT] /entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

Import finished

Database ready to use. Enjoy! ;)
```

I can then use a tool like SQLDeveloper to connect to `localhost:1521` and create tables, types, etc. So far so good!

However, the instant I kill this container (`docker stop` and `docker rm`), all the changes I've made to it get lost! In other words, the next time I run the container (with the exact same `docker run` command), it takes yet another 3 - 4 mins to initialize, and then all of my changes (table creates, etc.) from the last session are now gone!

Is there a way to tell Docker (maybe as an added arg to the `docker run` command) to store all the data somewhere on my host/local file system? For example, can I make a "data dir" under `~/myappdb/data` and then tell Docker and/or the Oracle DB living inside the container to store all of its data to `~/myappdb/data`, so that each time I kill + restart the container my data is persisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parameter `-v` or `--volume` of the [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command to bind the database data folder to a host folder:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -v ~/myappdb/data:/u01/app/oracle sath89/oracle-12c
```

On the documentation of the [image `sath89/oracle-12c`](https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-12c/), they bind the `/u01/app/oracle` folder of the container to the host folder `/my/oracle/data`.